Value of uninitialized pointer in C++
Context: I am still learning how to code in C++, and I know variables are assigned garbage values if not initialized.
I was wondering what value will an uninitialized pointer will have.
I was expecting it to have some garbage value just like any other variable.
I wrote a simple program:
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int *pptr;
   cout << pptr;
}

The output was:
0x8

Every time I ran it, it outputted the same.
I  really don't have any idea what is going on here.
Can anyone explain?

You are incorrect that uninitialised variables will have garbage values, that not what the current C++ standard says (though apparently this is changing). Instead it says that any attempt to get the value of an uninitialised variable means that the program has undefined behaviour, that's not the same thing, So to answer your question, always outputing the same value is one possibility that is allowed by the phrase 'undefined behaviour', so would always outputing a different value, so would the program crashing. All of these are possible when your program has undefined behaviour.

An uninitialized variable isn't assigned garbage. It isn't assigned anything. Often what you see is whatever happened to be in memory at the location being used by the variable, and that can be surprisingly consistent. Worse it can even be the value you expected, if you accidentally left the variable uninitialized. One of the most important things to remember about Undefined Behaviour (UB) is that the infinite pool of possibilities available to UB include the desired behaviour.

@user4581301 The fact that reading an uninitialised variable is UB means that a compiler can assign anything it likes to an uninitialised variable. Assigning a garbage value (or a specific value, or a random value) to an uninitialised variable would be perfectly correct behaviour if a compiler chose to do that.

True enough. Aayush, you'll find plenty of debugging systems take advantage of UB. Since the bahaviour is undefined the folks that implement the tools can make the program do anything they want, for good or ill. Usually they're aiming for the fastest possible program, so they don't do anything, but when building debug code they want to help you find errors and generally slow things down by inserting additional tests and writing special  "canary" values into memory.

If you see a really weird number, convert it to hexadecimal. If it's repetitious or kind-of looks like a word or phrase, it could be the compiler or library makers trying to tell you something important.

You really ought to avoid using namespace std - it is a bad habit to get into, and can silently change the meaning of your program when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (std is intentionally very short), or importing just the names you need into the smallest reasonable scope.

The value of the uninitialized pointer is indeterminate. It can be anything. The fact that you saw the same thing on every run of your program does not mean you should count on this behavior.
Note for instance, when I compile and run your program repeatedly I get the following outputs, all of which are unique.
0x10ad01b90
0x10ac01b90
0x101801b90
0x104301b90
0x104401b90
0x110501b90

Now, who knows what's actually at any of these memory addresses. Could be anything. This is why pointers need to be initialized before being used: to avoid undefined behavior in your program.
In modern C++ you should also carefully consider why you're using int *pptr; vs. a smart pointer. E.g. std::unique_ptr<int> pptr;.

Thanks alot! I will surely keep that in mind

I feel this answer misses the point. The behaviour is undefined, but it's not the case that the only possibilities here are different values for the pointer variable. Undefined behaviour is not constrained like that.

Yes, that's the difference between unspecified value and undefined behaviour.  This program has the latter (at least in C++23).
